# Updating a column value based on a value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, infopath

I have a two lists, List A and List B. In List A it has a field named "Quantity". In List B it has a column named "Availability". I want to know how to update the column "Availability" in List B in a specific row when i enter a value and save from "Quantity" field. Im using infopath for the forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a workflow for List A in SharePoint Designer to update list item as below:

[image]

Wait for "Quantity" field is not empty and then update "Availability" field in List B, set “Find the list Item” section to find a specific row.

Then in the workflow settings page in SharePoint workflow, tick "start workflow automatically when an item is created".

[image]